# a special question to the predicate

Tags: grammar

I've got a sentence: "Му sister's got five lessons today". I'm asked to put a special question to the predicate. I wonder, how I can do that! Can anyone?

Thanks in advance, Vic.

Comment: I assume it should be: What is your sister doing today?  To use Present Progressive to denote a planned action.

Comment: I doubt it's a planning action... 10 minutes before, for example, she didn't know about that. She had a phone call from her girl friend a minute ago, and it seems to be a bad surprise for her...

Comment: planned, of course... :-)))

Comment: Or, perhaps, it's impossible to put a special question to the verb "to have" in the predicate function?

Comment: I mean a context  when you ask in order to know about his/her sister's plans for today and the interlocutor answers that her plan was having 5 lessons.

Comment: No, I want to figure out what special question can be put to the verb "to have" in such a sentence.

Comment: You can ask, "How many lessons does she have today?" If you don't know anything about lessons, "Do you have anything planned for today?" "Are you doing anything today?" "What do you have going on today?" "Do you have any plans [for] today?" "What's your schedule look like today?"

Comment: @Jim exactly that was my point that a question to know the sister's plans for today should be asked, but the OP wants some special question for the word to have

Comment: @TurkanAlisoy - 3 of my 5 suggestions use *to have*

Comment: I support your point, I just stated what the OP wants. When you ask for instance, How many lessons does she have? When does she have five lessons? you have interrogative pronouns for the words FIVE and TODAY.  The OP wants the same for the predicate TO HAVE GOT.